# Getting data from PHP with AJAX for the first time

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

So i simply use this updateData function to get values from my php file it works after the first interval, but I would like to get first data after the page loads so I've tried doing var

```
var dataset=[];
updateData();
```

Before the intervals starts but dataset is still not updated immidiately I get empty array []

```
function updateData(){
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'parser.php',         
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                dataset = result;
            },
    });

}
<?php 
    $datasetJSON = array();

    for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
        $datasetJSON[] = rand(1,1000);
    }
    echo json_encode($datasetJSON);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is understanding that AJAX is not synced!

That means your code will keep running and not wait for the AJAX call to return. You could think of AJAX calls as threads that will run seperately of your main thread.

```
  var dataset=[];
  updateData();
  console.log(dataset); // will execute immediately!
  function updateData(){
      $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'parser.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              cache: false,
              success: function(result) {
                  dataset = result;
                  console.log(dataset); // now it's updated
              },
      });
  }
```

You *could* call AJAX synced:

```
  var dataset=[];
  updateData();
  console.log(dataset); // now it's updated
  function updateData(){
      $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'parser.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              cache: false,
              async: false, // <-- This will sync the AJAX call (and freeze the browser)
              success: function(result) {
                  dataset = result;
                  console.log(dataset); // now it's updated
              },
      });
  }
```

However, it defeats the purpose of AJAX. You should learn how the deal with callback functions.

Comment: I do get that I want to make a separate call just for the initiaton and then use AJAX to update values.

Comment: Does `async: false` give you the result you want?

Comment: This kinda works partially, since now I do get the values immidiately but first value after that from synced ajax is exactly the same and the one after that is random.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the random seed in PHP, not with JavaScript / AJAX / JQuery. Or maybe you console.log() the same value twice on different parts of your code?

Comment: I've checked console.log is not repeated so I run the program I get the values I wait 3 seconds I get the same values I wait 3 seconds and then i get the random values. Random values in php are quite simple in my code 
    for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
        $datasetJSON[] = rand(1,1000);
    }
I do not this messes it up.

Comment: Hm, it's a `POST` **and** `cache` is `false`, so the only thing that comes to mind is that PHP is really providing the same "random" values for each first access (you should be able to verify this with your browser console's `Network` tab). I suggest you initialize your `srand()`: http://php.net/manual/de/function.srand.php

Answer (score 0):

just detect the page loaded or not then call the function like this. is this you want?

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    updateData();
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: var dataset=[];
jQuery(window).load(function () {
        updateData();
    });
console.log(dataset);

dataset is still empty

Answer (score 0):

Add your ajax call on document ready time like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        tableselect = jQuery(this).val() ;
            var data_pro = {
                    action: 'update_record',
                    tableselect: tableselect
                    };

                    jQuery.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType : 'html',
                                url: ajaxurl,
                                data: data_pro,
                                  success: function(data){

                                    }
                            });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: will you show me the url and what values do you need from them